# How to cache a json proxy

Tags: c#, json, caching, proxy

I am looking for the best way to cache a json proxy on .NET with C#.

The web service we are using restricts the number of hits per IP and is periodically unavailable. Luckily the data isn't very volitile, but it does change.

Ideally I'd like to do is cache the web response only when the request is valid. We would determine a vaid response by two factors, the http response code and the json code doesn't give us a "too many requests" error.

I'd like to store the proxy request in cache using the proxied URL and query string so we could use the same proxy for multiple external resources and multiple queries.

I'd also like to store the request either on disk as a file or in the data base in case the URL is unavailable and the Cache is empty.

Here is the proposed process:

1. Check the Cache for results by using query string
2. If the cached versions exists use it. If not make a new request.
3. If the reqeust succeeds, store a new set of results to the cache and write the results to disk or database or disk.
4. If that request fails use the file or database cached version.

I have read the MSDN articles and a few other blog posts, but it would be great to get a specific example on how to do this efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: this is not a forum. Do you have any *specific* question regarding this problem?

Comment: Your proposed process sounds entirely reasonable to me. Go for it, and if you hit a problem, that's when you want to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: question edited to pose specific question per vidstige's comment

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, this was a long time ago. I believe I used something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ or something else that was popular at the time.